# logstash ignores elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have this fresh installation of logstash with the following config:

```
input{
 rabbitmq {
    ...
 }
}
output{
  elasticsearch {
    index => "myname-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    hosts => [ "elasticsearch:9200" ]
  }
}
```

My problem is that logstash is ignoring the index value and sends the logs to the default "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" index

With such a basic config, I don't understand why the setting is being ignored. At first I thought it was the --auto-reload not working, but stop/start has same result

Comment: Can you show the logs you get when running logstash with `--debug`?

Comment: See if you have any extra config files in your config directory, or perhaps an older copy of logstash still running.

Comment: Thanks Alain!! That put me in the right track. I was testing in Docker, and I was testing in the right instance